# Jenkins and GitLab -- Gitlab Hook plugin is the right choice?

Tags: jenkins, gitlab

There are so many posts about this, and being inexperienced in Git doesn't help to get a good grip on this.

I just joined a new company that dont have CI at all, so jumped on the opportunity to create a proof of concept (using Jenkins locally on my Windows box for now, until I get a dedicated server for it). I've used and semi-configured Jenkins in the past, using SVN, and it was so simple and fast to get it working. In this company, they don't use SVN, only GitLab (I believe its private - we have our own site, not .gitlab.com), and nothing works for me.

I followed a few turorials, but mainly [this](https://medium.com/@teeks99/continuous-integration-with-jenkins-and-gitlab-fa770c62e88a) seemed like the one that meets my needs. It didn't work (the reasons and symptoms are probably worth a post of its own).

When I look at Gitlab Hook plugin in Jenkins, I see a big red warning saying it is not safe ("Gitlab API token stored and displayed in plain text").

So my question, for this POC that i am working on, how serious is this warning? Should I avoid this plugin and then this method altogether because of this?

And while i'm at it, I might also throw an additional general question to open up my options here ... If I want Jenkins to work with Gitlab (meaning, I checkin something and it triggers a build), do I **absolutely need** to use the SSH method, or it could work with HTTPS as well?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is indeed [SECURITY-263 / CVE-2018-1000196](https://jenkins.io/security/advisory/2018-05-09/#SECURITY-263)

> Gitlab Hook Plugin does not encrypt the Gitlab API token used to access Gitlab. This can be used by users with master file system access to obtain GitHub credentials.
>
> Additionally, the Gitlab API token round-trips in its plaintext form, and is displayed in a regular text field to users with Overall/Administer permission. This exposes the API token to people viewing a Jenkins administrator’s screen, browser extensions, cross-site scripting vulnerabilities, etc.
>
> As of publication of this advisory, there is no fix.

So:

> how serious is this warning?

Serious, but it does require access to the Jenkins server filesystem, or it requires Jenkins administration level. So that risk can be documented, acknowledged and, for now, set aside, provided mitigation steps are in place, ie.:

- the access to the Jenkins server is properly monitored
- the list of Jenkins admin account is properly and regularly reviewed.

> do I absolutely need to use the SSH method, or it could work with HTTPS as well?

You can use https for accessing GitLab repositories in a Jenkins job.
But for the GitLab hook plugin, SSH remains the recommended way, considering you would use a token (instead of a user account name/password), that you can revoke at any time.

Comment: Thank you. I'll open a different question for how to use https, since I only need a POC for now.